# The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth-facebook

I am using Devise with the omniauth-facebook gem in a rails 4.2.7 app.  I am presently getting the following error, `The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController`.  I setup the app following this guide, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview.

My files look like the following,

**routes.rb**

```
# easy routes for devise
  devise_scope :user do

    get 'login', to: "devise/sessions#new"
    get 'signup', to: "devise/registrations#new"
    # delete 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => {
    :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',
    :controllers => { 
      :omniauth_callbacks => "callbacks",
      registrations: 'registrations' 
    }
  }
```

**devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
   callback_url: ENV['FB_CALLBACK'],
   :scope => 'email',
   :info_fields => 'email'
```

**models/user.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
         :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

**callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

The error, is occurring when I try to login to the app via Facebook.

Comment: Could you explain when the error is happening (e.g. when you are trying to login?)

Comment: I just amended my question.

Comment: I think problem is with your controller, That is supposed to be a name spaced with User . As per the devise wiki it should be like `class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` and the path is `app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`